# Exception in Application constructor - Cannot Start a Class

Tags: java, javafx, constructor

**I'm unable to create a constructor from "GUIController".. The program runs if i delete this line 
"GUIController(){myModel = new TheModel(this)"
but i still need it in other part. Please help!

**

```
package theclient;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class GUIController extends Application {

    TheModel myModel;

    GUIController(){
        myModel = new TheModel(this);
    }

    //public void init(){}

    public TextArea myTextArea;
    public TextField myTextField;

    // Button and text field actions
    public void myButtonAction() {
        sendMsg();
    }

    public void myTextFieldAction() {
        sendMsg();
    }

    // Append coming message
    public void displayMsg(String comingMSG) {
        System.out.println("Receive 01");
        myTextArea.appendText(comingMSG);
    }

    public void sendMsg() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Send 01");
            myModel.myChatServer.tellOthers(myTextField.getText());
        } catch (RemoteException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(GUIController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("GUI.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new GUIController();
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The Second class. I'd be thankful if you can suggest any edits to the code. Thanks in advance for your efforts.

```
package theclient;

import common.ChatServerInt;
import common.ClientInt;
import java.rmi.NotBoundException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class TheModel implements ClientInt {

    public GUIController myCtrl;
    ChatServerInt myChatServer;

    TheModel(GUIController myCtrl) {
        this.myCtrl = myCtrl;
    }

    public ChatServerInt connection() {
        if (myChatServer == null) {
            try {
                Registry reg = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(1111);
                myChatServer = (ChatServerInt) reg.lookup("ChatService");
                myChatServer.register(this);
                myChatServer.tellOthers("I'm here!");
            } catch (RemoteException | NotBoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(TheModel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        } return myChatServer;
    }

    @Override
    public void receive(String msg) throws RemoteException {
        myCtrl.displayMsg(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error? (Just guessing - the constructor probably needs to call the base class constructor.)

Comment: Just making the `GUIController` constructor `public` should help...

Answer (score 2):

Following the [Model-view-controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) design pattern, the model shouldn't be holding a reference to its controller.  If the controller needs to respond to changes in the model's data, then this can be done with properties and listeners.  The model holds a property (here, a [StringProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/StringProperty.html)) and the controller listens for changes to the property.

For your code, this means storing the `msg` in a `StringProperty`.  The controller, after constructing the model, attaches a `ChangeListener` that calls `displayMsg` when the model receives a message.

Using a property and listener, `TheModel` no longer stores a reference to `GUIController` and does not take a `GUIController` as a parameter in its constructor.

`GUIController` would look something like this:

```
public class GUIController extends Application {
 ...
TheModel myModel;
 ...
GUIController(){
    myModel = new TheModel();
    // Listen for changes in the msg StringProperty and call displayMessage when it changes
    myModel.getMsgProperty().addListener(msg -> this.displayMsg(msg));
}
 ...
```

Note that the constructor for `GUIController` no longer needs to pass `this` to the constructor `TheModel`.  (In general, [avoid passing `this` outside of the constructor](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=252).  An object is not fully constructed until the constructor returns.)

`TheModel`  would look something like this:

```
public class TheModel implements ClientInt {
 ...
private StringProperty msgProperty;
 ...
//  remember to add a getter and setter for msgProperty!
 ...
@Override
public void receive(String msg) throws RemoteException {
    // When a message is received, listeners attached to msgProperty will execute when setValue is called
    msgProperty.setValue(msg);
}
```